# Sine Wave Generation (DAC) with/without LUT

Tags: verilog, dac, waveform

I am currently working with the Xilinx Basys3 FPGA board and one of my task is to generate an analog sine wave (for input into oscilloscope) with the PMOD DAC module. I have thus far successfully generated a variable peak and trough value for my square wave as well as the frequency. However I am having difficulty understanding the various resources online on how I can go about generating a sine wave through DDS because mainly...

1. I am new to EE and does not understand how DDS work
2. Uncertain of how to input a lookup table (although I have found http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Sine-Generator-Calculator.phtml to be of help in getting the numerical decimal values)

I understand that somewhere in the code I will inverse the first half of the wave to produce the negative half. How do I generate a sine wave without a LUT?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169550/sine-wave-in-fpga

Comment: You only need to store 1/4 cycle. Consider 0-\$\pi/2\$, the next \$\pi/2\$ is just the reverse in time of the first, and the last half of the cycle is the same as the first with the sign reversed.

Comment: For the table just write a program in your favorite language to spit out the values in the format you require.

Comment: The cutest way to do sine wave is through COORDIC (put precisely that into wikipedia). The Xilinx tools can generate a COORDIC block parametrically, though it's more fun and instructive to implement it from primitives. It does away with the lookup table, you can extend it to any precision on both phase angle and sine value without changing the fundamental process. It uses only integers, with bit shifts and adds, and is very efficient. If it makes your head explode, just whack a column of numbers into Excel, with the next column being =sine(left_hand_column), and you're (nearly) done.

Comment: You are having difficulties and uncertainties and you don't understand something. How can this be answered without specifics. Sorry, voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sine wave in FPGA](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169550/sine-wave-in-fpga)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer on how to use LUT

Here's a description of Analog Device's DDS chips. http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/all-about-direct-digital-synthesis.html. Here you can pick how to make different frequencies with one lookup table and one stepping rate.(=tuning word and phase accumulator)